# MATLAB: Random Sample from Array with NaNs, need index

Tags: matlab, random

I am trying to get a random sample of a matrix which includes `NaN`s, but I need the indices as well.

I have tried `randsample(matrix(~isnan(matrix)),10);` but I get only the values of the matrix and not the index here. Since multiple positions may have the same value, the index is very important.

If my matrix is:

```matlab
[ NaN 2 3  
 3 4 5  
 1 NaN 6]
```

and the random sample value is `3`, I would like to also see the indices `(2,1)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First find the index and then find the corresponding value. Use [`ind2sub`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ind2sub.html) to convert linear index to row/column subscripts.

```
[r, c] = ind2sub(size(matrix), randsample(find(~isnan(matrix)),1));
val = matrix(r,c);
```